# PowerPoint and WPF

Tags: wpf, powerpoint

I really need a way of loading a .ppt document in my wpf application. Can anyone give me a hint, code sample?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the [following](http://social.expression.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/9db90c63-c302-4a1a-b813-c99df9824777/#) discussion thread. Also Dr.WPF got an interesting article that might help you as well: [Hosting Office in WPF Application](http://www.drwpf.com/blog/Home/tabid/36/EntryID/3/Default.aspx)
However consider license costs will be quite high for your scenario...

Answer (score 0):

According to this artice the DSO Framer is no longer supported. Have to look for something else.

Comment: Add a comment rather than a new answer

Answer (score -1):

You may need to elaborate a bit more on your particular need to get a practical answer.
I don't think hosting PowerPoint (ppt) is a good option because it requires ppt to be installed on the target machine.... and if the target machine has ppt then you can use its **API to save the document as HTML** and open it in a **WebBrowser** control.

If the target machine doesn't have powerpoint you may look into some online file conversion service and try hooking up there to convert to HTML and still use **WebBrowser** control.

I definitely don't recommend wasting your time with DSOFramer - it's very unstable at best and it will just feel like you're one step away from making it work for a while but it doesn't work.

Another option is of course to write your own parser for ppt files, the OfficeOpenXML version of the files is definitely "parseable". I've done that for Word docx and it's relatively easy to get the course data out of the document - say shapes, text... - but the devil there is in the details. There are a zillion little features to implement.