# Are there any good resources for microsoft multipoint sdk development?

Tags: reference, sdk, multipoint

i just manage to get myself in a tight spot, it seems our company is playing with the idea of developing a microsoft multipoint app, and the funny thing is that we're not really much of a .net developer, as we're mostly just LAMP guys with Perl.

and to top it off, i need to provide some estimate to my boss about how long development of these apps are going to take by tomorrow noon. so the features will probably be something like a powerpoint macro which allows you to create questions for quiz which will allows multiple users with multiple mices to interact with.

with so many unknowns, very little timeline and worst, not much useful link even when i pray to the mighty Google, i'm as good as toast :(

anybody know of any good references which might be helpful?
thanks
~dead man walking

Updates:
so far there's [a few videos and docs available online by the good people of Microsoft.](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=f851122a-4925-4788-bc39-409644ce0f9b&displayLang=en#filelist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SDK you linked to was for WPF.
You could try embedding powerpoint inside WPF but I wouldn't want to do this myself!

[PowerPoint and WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594052/powerpoint-and-wpf)

Alternatively you could write your own PowerPoint editor in WPF and then export it to XML (Powerpoint 2007 is in XML format).

Comment: Well the Multipoint SDK is a WPF library. Thus you'll need to use it in a WPF application. AFAIK