# WPF control for viewing Office Documents

Tags: wpf, ms-office

I am looking for a way to view Microsoft Office and PDF documents within a WPF application.  Does anyone know about an Office viewer control that works well in WPF?

Thanks

Jay

Answer (score 1):

are you trying to [do something like this?](http://www.drwpf.com/blog/Home/tabid/36/EntryID/3/Default.aspx)
if so here was a [previous discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594052/powerpoint-and-wpf) but unfortunately i think they have yet to find a good answer to it.